# MSTest tests succeed if run in isolation, fail if run with other tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, mstest

I've bumped into this really odd situation where, if I run all my tests together, certain tests will fail (about 7 of them). But if I run just the tests inside the class (they are all part of the same class), then they pass. The test project is a Windows Phone 8.1 MSTest, and I tried running it both with Resharper test runner and MSTest test runner and they both show the same problem. Here's my TestInitialize code:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Init()
{
     ResolveDependencies();
     var adsApiService = ServiceLocator
         .Current
         .GetInstance<IApiService<ListAdsReply, PublicAdsEndPoint>>();            
     var navigationService = new NavigationServiceMock();
     var mainPageTrackingService = ServiceLocator
         .Current
         .GetInstance<IMainPageTrackingService>();
     var adInsertionTrackingService = ServiceLocator
         .Current
         .GetInstance<IAdInsertionTrackingService>();
     var connectionService = ServiceLocator
         .Current
         .GetInstance<IConnectionService>();
     _windowsApiService = new WindowsApiServiceMock();
     var contactAboutTrackingService = ServiceLocator
         .Current
         .GetInstance<IContactAboutTrackingService>();
     var filtersTrackingService = ServiceLocator
         .Current
         .GetInstance<IFiltersTrackingService>();
            var filtersService = ServiceLocator
         .Current
         .GetInstance<IFiltersService>();
     var messageHelperMock = new MessageHelperMock();
     _mainPageViewModel = new MainPageViewModel(adsApiService, navigationService, mainPageTrackingService, adInsertionTrackingService, connectionService, _windowsApiService, contactAboutTrackingService,filtersTrackingService, filtersService, messageHelperMock);
}
```

The `ResolveDependencies` method doesn't do anything special besides registering dependencies in a Unity container, registering it with `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider` and doing some Automapper configurations. No async code there.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GivenParameterIsProvidedThenFetchDataShouldReturnValidData()
{
    _mainPageViewModel
        .SearchParams
        .Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("lim", "5"));
    var searchParams = _mainPageViewModel.SearchParams;
    await _mainPageViewModel.FetchData(searchParams);

    var list = _mainPageViewModel.AdsList;
    Assert.IsNotNull(list);
}
```

This is one of the failing tests.

```
public async Task<ListAdsReplyViewModel> FetchData(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters)
{
    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    _cancellationTokenSource
        .CancelAfter(Constants.TimeToCancelAsyncOperations);
    AddSearchKeywordToSearchParams();
    var result = await _listAdsReplyApiService
        .GetWithParametersAsync(_cancellationTokenSource, parameters);
    var vm = new ListAdsReplyViewModel
    {
        Ads = new List<AdInfoViewModel>()
    };
    foreach (var listAd in result.ListAds)
    {
        var listAdDto = Mapper.Map<ListAdDto>(listAd);
        var adInfo = new AdInfoViewModel(_navigationService, _mainPageTrackingService)
        {
            ListAdDto = listAdDto
        };
            vm.Ads.Add(adInfo);
     }
     vm.NextPage = result.NextPage;
     vm.ConfigEtag = result.ConfigEtag;
     vm.Sorting = result.Sorting;
     TotalAds = result.ListAdsCounterMap.AllAds;
     return vm;
}

private void AddSearchKeywordToSearchParams()
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchKeyWord))
     {
         var searchKeyword = SearchParams
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "q");
         if (!searchKeyword.Equals(null))  
             SearchParams.Remove(searchKeyword);
         SearchParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("q", SearchKeyWord));
     }
}
```

And this are the methods under test. The problem seems to happen when `foreach((var listAd in result.ListAds)` is called. It's like `GetWithParametersAsync(_cancellationTokenSource, parameters);` is not being awaited, because I get the following error for the failing tests:

```
Test method App.Tests.Integration.App.Shared.ViewModels.MainPageViewModelTests.GivenParameterIsProvidedThenFetchDataShouldReturnValidData threw exception: 
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 

Mapping types:
ListAd -> ListAdDto
Core.Api.Models.PublicAds.ListAd -> Core.Dto.ListAdDto

Destination path:
ListAdDto

Source value:
Core.Api.Models.PublicAds.ListAd ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    at Core.Bootstrap.AutoMapperConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__12(ListAd src, ListAdDto dest)
   at AutoMapper.Internal.MappingExpression`2.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<AfterMap>b__0(Object src, Object dest)
   at AutoMapper.TypeMap.<get_AfterMap>b__40_0(Object src, Object dest)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at App.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel.<FetchData>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at App.Tests.Integration.App.Shared.ViewModels.MainPageViewModelTests.<GivenParameterIsProvidedThenFetchDataShouldReturnValidData>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this break when you run any other tests or only when a certain one is run? (Ie. is it any combination of tests that causes the breakdown or is it only a certain combination / certain test that causes the problem to manifest?)  Second, have you fired up the debugger and traced the steps to see where something is going wrong?  The exception says you have a null ref error.  It also looks like it might have to do with automapper.  Try there.

Comment: Have you taken into account that MSTest will run your tests multi-threaded - and that by executing a single test you are forcing a single-thread ? Be very careful that all your tests are UNIT tests and have no dependency on each other, in the sequence of execution, or the possiblity that shared resources might have already been instantiated (or being in the process of instantiation) by another tests running in parallel.

Comment: @Becuzz the tests break when I run the whole bunch (400+ tests, I have unit and integration tests). If I run just the tests that fail, which happen to be in the same class, then they pass. PhillipH has a point, it looks like the tests are running multi-threaded but the code that maps ListAdDto is being run and not awaited as it should, so the NullRef exception is thrown

Comment: @PhillipH You're right, that's probably what's happening, it's running multi-threaded. The tests are integration tests, pointing to a live api and are not being awaited as they should for some reason. I haven't found any dependencies or shared resources other than the ones found in `TestInitilialize`.

Answer (score 3):

As this was accepted in the comments, I've reposted as an Answer;

"Have you taken into account that MSTest will run your tests multi-threaded - and that by executing a single test you are forcing a single-thread ? Be very careful that all your tests are UNIT tests and have no dependency on each other, in the sequence of execution, or the possiblity that shared resources might have already been instantiated (or being in the process of instantiation) by another tests running in parallel. "